# Python dictionary comprehension for a object method

Tags: python, optimization, dictionary, error-handling, list-comprehension

I need to find a way to resolve the following error in a dictionary comprehension

```
from collections import Counter
from operator import attrgetter

consider points a list of object 

p  = returns[0]
p.class
2

Counter(map(attrgetter("class"), points))
Counter({1: 1314, 2: 1050})

p.get_point_source_id()
13612
```

when i use the same approach i get this error message

```
Counter(map(attrgetter("get_point_source_id()"), points))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<editor selection>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Point' object has no attribute 'get_point_source_id()'
```

when i use this form:

```
Counter(map(attrgetter("get_point_source_id"), returns))
```

i get a dictionary where each point is unique. In order to get the dictionary i need to write a slow loop

```
dict_point_source_id = dict()
for p in returns:
     dict_point_source_id[p.get_point_source_id()] = dict_point_source_id.get(p.get_point_source_id(), 0) + 1

print dict_point_source_id
{13612: 2364}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_point_source_id` is a method of your class, so use [`operator.methodcaller`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.methodcaller) instead:

```
from operator import methodcaller
map(methodcaller("get_point_source_id"), points)
```

### EIDT:

**How do I know what I know?**

Install [ipython](http://ipython.org/), In ipython-qtconsole, use `*` and `?` magics to search all attributes matches the given pattern:

```
In [356]: import operator

In [357]: operator.*attr*?
operator.__delattr__
operator.__getattribute__
operator.__setattr__
operator.attrgetter

In [358]: operator.*meth*?
operator.methodcaller
```

Comment: thanks zhangxaochen but this give a list and not a dictionary

Comment: @Gianni, it's just a snippet, wrap that with `Counter(...`

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, use a generator expression like so

```
ct = Counter(pt.get_point_source_id() for pt in points)
```